# How to secure is JWT Token access data

Tags: ajax, api, rest, jwt

I am currently working on a REST API for a project of my own. To secure the API I want to use a JWT token for the first time. If I understand the principle correctly, I have to send the username and password with the first request (/authorize) and then receive the token with which I can continue working. But how can I transmit the user data securely? I use AJAX client-side to send the request. It would be disadvantageous to store the access data in the clear .js file.

**EDIT: Example**

```
let credentials = []
credentials['username'] = 'user'
credentials['password'] = 'pass'

let serializedData = JSON.stringify(credentials)

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.example.com/authorize",
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: serializedData
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log("Successful: " + data);
}).fail(function (data) {
    console.log("Error: " + data)
})
```

So somehow I need to store user credentials. How can I do this in a secure way?

Comment: Transporting user data from client to server should already be handled by 2-way SSL.  Can you elaborate on what security concerns you have?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by 2-way SSL? My concerns are that someone can just use the console to get username and password and create their own JWT token that way

Comment: The JWT contains a signature which only the server can generate using a private server key.  If any alteration of the JWT took place, the server can immediately detect that it has been tampered with.

Comment: I have added an example to show what I mean. With the first request the user data must be sent somehow. How can I do this in a secure way?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure way"? Why not use SSL for this? Also, is this about storing credentials, or about sending them?

Comment: Its more the question how to store the data. For secure connection I already use SSL

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. "With the first request the user data must be sent somehow. How can I do this in a secure way" - how does this relate to your question of storing any data?

Comment: I don't know if I misunderstood, but why would you want to find a way to secure credentials if you will always send the same ones?